# Content Assist (Left Ctrl + Space) not working in Eclipse (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, eclipse, windows-8.1, content-assist

I am using
Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Operating System: Windows 8.1 Pro
English(US) styled keyboard.

**Issue**:

Content Assist is not working in my Eclipse when I am pressing <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. Whereas it is working with <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

**Expecting Solution**

It should start working with <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

**Already Tried**

1. Tried Keybinding with <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> but the eclipse field is not accepting it but it is accepting <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

   Eclipse>Windows>Preferences>General>Keys

   [Screenshot of the setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOBcP.png)
2. Eclipse>Windows>Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advance

   [Screenshot of Proposal Kinds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewAS4.png)
3. Removed all languages from windows except one English (US)

   [Language Setting in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBhxS.png)

   [Language Setting in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLlI3.png)

   [Language Setting in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71KdX.png)

   [Language Setting in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWWj9.png)

Answer (score 0):

> teried Keybinding with Left Ctrl + Space but the eclipse field is not accepting it but it is accepting Right Ctrl + Space.

That is strange, maybe the left Ctrl button is not working at all? Just to rule it out, you can try opening an On-Screen keyboard (Windows key, then type on screen keyboard), click on the left CTRL button, and see that the on screen keyboard is receiving this input.

Comment: Hi Edan.. the Right Ctrl key is working fine.. There is no such issue with Right Ctrl key.

Comment: Hi Edan.. the Left Ctrl key is working fine.. There is no such issue with Left Ctrl key.
I tried with on-Screen keyboard to set the key bindings, and it binds with Ctrl+Space but while pressing Left Ctrl + Space  it presses the Right Ctrl at the same time. So while binding it tkes ctrl+spce in input